# How to add header authorization to node https request

Tags: node.js

Im tryng a get method that i need to pass a authentication via header but its not working
one type of authentication is  adding a key : Authorization and value : "Token {token code}
the second type is by adding a Basic auth to the header with username/password. How can i achieve this?
this is my request.js

```
var http = require('https');

var header =  { 
    'Authorization': 'Token token code'
}
var optionsget = {
    host : 'kc.kobotoolbox.org', // here only the domain name
    // (no http/https !)
    port : 443,
     path : '/api/v1/forms/191797/form.json', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
    method : 'GET' ,
    headers: header
};
http.request(optionsget,function(res){
    console.log(res);
    var body = '';
    res.on('data',function(chunk){
        console.log(chunk);
        body+= chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
        // var dados = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(body);
    })
}).end();
```

Second attempt

```
   var http = require('https');


    var username = 'user';
    var password = 'pw';
    var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

    var header = {'Host':'kc.humanitarianresponse.info/api/v1/data', 'Authorization': auth};
    var optionsget = {
        host : 'kc.humanitarianresponse.info', // here only the domain name
        // (no http/https !)
        port : 443,
         path : '/api/v1/forms/191797/form.json', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
        method : 'GET' ,
        'Authorization': auth
    };
    http.request(optionsget,function(res){
        console.log(res);
        var body = '';
        res.on('data',function(chunk){
            console.log(chunk);
            body+= chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function(){
            // var dados = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(body);
        })
    }).end();
```

the error i get is Authentication credentials were not provided.

Comment: where do you define the `headers` variable in use on your `optionsget` object?  What do you do with the `auth` and `header` variables you're defining later on?

Comment: edited, changing the order of the declarations didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example shown "**How to call LinkedIn API end point from NodeJs**", since if we call it from front-end then it'll give **CORS** issue.

Let's say your API URL is `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/{ServiceName}`

And it's a `GET` request.

```
var token = 'your-token';
var options = {
   host: 'api.linkedin.com',
   port: 443,
   path: '/v2/me',
   headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
   }   
};


request = https.get(options, function(res){
   var body = "";
   res.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data;
   });
   res.on('end', function() {
    //here we have the full response, html or json object
      console.log(body);
   });
   res.on('error', function(e) {
      onsole.log("Got error: " + e.message);
   });
});
```